# How to make a navbar active tab height is bigger compare to other tabs?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav

Examples of what I want to achieve:

[image]
[image]

Here's my HTML code:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs flex-nowrap" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" style="margin-left: -1px">
    <button
      class="nav-link active"
      id="home-tab"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#home"
      type="button"
    >
      About
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <button
      class="nav-link"
      id="personalize-tab"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#personalize"
      type="button"
    >
      Personslize
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <button
      class="nav-link"
      id="http-proxy-tab"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#http-proxy"
      type="button"
    >
      Http Title
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" id="data-processor-display" style="display: none">
    <button
      class="nav-link"
      id="data-processor"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#data-processor-click"
      type="button"
    >
      DSP Titel
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" id="mate-setting-display" style="display: none">
    <button
      class="nav-link"
      id="mate-settings"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#mate-setting-click"
      type="button"
    >
      MS Title
    </button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" id="mate-manage-display" style="display: none">
    <button
      class="nav-link"
      id="mate-manage"
      data-bs-toggle="tab"
      data-bs-target="#mate-manage-click"
      type="button"
    >
      MM Title
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And this is the CSS I tried:

```css
.nav-tabs .nav-item.show .nav-link,
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  color: rgb(5, 5, 5);
  background-color: rgb(249, 249, 249);
  border: 1px solid rgb(198 198 198);
  height: 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

I am using bootstrap, `data-bs-toggle="tab"`.
I want the active tab a little bit taller compared to other tabs.

Comment: So what have you tried, and how did it not work as intended? I can't tell from your overly vague explanation, what _exactly_ you want to achieve here.

Comment: i want the current active tab bit higher sir, compare to other inactive tabs , like which is in MySql Workbench ->Server -> Data Impoert , I dont have enough reputation to post images sir ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it by using a negative margin on the active tab coupled with increasing the bottom padding by the same exact distance.

Example:

```css
.nav-link.active {
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding-bottom: calc(0.5rem + 2px)
}
```

In the above CSS, the `2px` is the distance by which the active item is moved up, without affecting anything else.

Note I'm setting the `padding-bottom` to `calc(0.5rem + 2px)` because the default bootstrap bottom padding on tab controls is `0.5rem`. If you're using a theme which sets that padding to a different value, you'll need to adjust accordingly.

See it working:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
.nav-link.active {
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding-bottom: calc(0.5rem + 2px)
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link active"
          id="home-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#home"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="home"
          aria-selected="true"
        >
          Home
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="profile-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#profile"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="profile"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Profile
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="contact-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#contact"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="contact"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Contact
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade show active"
        id="home"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="home-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="profile"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="profile-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="contact"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="contact-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</body>
```

Alternatively, you can increase the `padding-top` instead of the bottom one, thus making the text of the tab no longer go up along with the rest of the tab button. Or you can even split the `2px` gained by the negative margin between the bottom and top padding:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
.nav-link.active {
  margin-top: -2px;
  padding-bottom: calc(0.5rem + 1px);
  padding-top: calc(0.5rem + 1px)
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link active"
          id="home-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#home"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="home"
          aria-selected="true"
        >
          Home
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="profile-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#profile"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="profile"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Profile
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="contact-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#contact"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="contact"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Contact
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade show active"
        id="home"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="home-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="profile"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="profile-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="contact"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="contact-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</body>
```

Obviously, feel free to modify `2px` to any other value you see fit considering your use case.

If you decide to work with bigger values, you might want to transition between states, so the button doesn't look like it's jumping into position:

```css
body {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}
.nav-link.active {
  margin-top: -16px;
  padding-bottom: calc(0.5rem + 10px);
  padding-top: calc(0.5rem + 6px);
}
.nav-link {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.5,0,.3,1);
  transition-duration: .2s;
  transition-property: margin-top, padding-top, padding-bottom;
}
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link active"
          id="home-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#home"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="home"
          aria-selected="true"
        >
          Home
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="profile-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#profile"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="profile"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Profile
        </button>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
        <button
          class="nav-link"
          id="contact-tab"
          data-toggle="tab"
          data-target="#contact"
          type="button"
          role="tab"
          aria-controls="contact"
          aria-selected="false"
        >
          Contact
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade show active"
        id="home"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="home-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="profile"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="profile-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
      <div
        class="tab-pane fade"
        id="contact"
        role="tabpanel"
        aria-labelledby="contact-tab"
      >
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
  <script
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Fy6S3B9q64WdZWQUiU+q4/2Lc9npb8tCaSX9FK7E8HnRr0Jz8D6OP9dO5Vg3Q9ct"
    crossorigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</body>
```